# Git subtree issue when using multiple subtrees

Tags: git, git-subtree, subtree

I have a single mono repo that is being split to be 3 separate repos:

- Repo A: Feature one
- Repo B: Feature two
- Repo C: Dev repo that contains A and B as subtrees

The overall goal is to be able to develop in repo C, and consistently push changes for Repo A & B to their respective remote repos. An example flow would be something like this:

- Make changes to code in Repo C as well as subtrees A & B
- Commit work to Repo C
- Run the following commands on subtree A

  - `git subtree split -P featureA --squash --rejoin -m "Commit message"`
  - If changes were made to subtree A (based on split result) then `git subtree push -P featureA {remoteA} {targetBranchA}`
- Then run the same commands on subtree B

  - `git subtree split -P featureB --squash --rejoin -m "Commit message"`
  - If changes were made to subtree B (based on split result) then `git subtree push -P featureB {remoteB} {targetBranchB}`
- Then push the changes resulting from the subtree commands to the working branch on repo C

The issue I am seeing is that the `--rejoin` functionality of git subtree appears to not function correctly when using a workflow like this with multiple subtrees. If changes are only made to repo A for instance, each successive `split` command run successfully searches to the last `--rejoin` point found and stops (for example searches the last say 2 commits in the history).

However, when changes are made to both repos and each one runs the `split` command, the command now always searches the entire history failing to recognize any checkpoints from a previous `--rejoin`.

Wondering if anyone can provide any insight into what I may be doing wrong or how I could tweak this workflow to get it to work the way I would like?

I had played around extensively with variations of different subtree commands and trying to get it to rebuild its history with no luck.